# Can repeated measures ANOVA be used with only 2 time points?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I am analyzing my data of my experiment and I have a question concerning the repeated measures ANOVA. I have 2 independent variables (temperature and salinity), 1 dependent which is length and 2 measuring points (3rd and 7th day) of the experiment.

So my question is, can I use repeated measures ANOVA when I only have 2 time points? I read somewhere that you need more than 3.

In case I can't do it, is it possible to run a 3-way ANOVA and set temperature, salinity and day (3rd and 7th) as a factor?

Comment: You can do it with 2 time points.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible with 2 time points. The idea of a repeated measures ANOVA is to compare data within subjects. That is, to compare the data a participant had at T1 versus the data at T2 (and T3 and so on). This is for example before and after an intervention.

In short, yes a repeated measures ANOVA is possible with 2 time points.

A 3-way ANOVA is not the analysis you want, because unlike your variable "day", the variables temperature and salinity are not within-subjects.